# Create new views programmatically and manage them

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm new in Objective-C and I'm start to work on app that will have a few View's. I want to create them 100% programmatically without `XIB` files. I understand that I have to create my `ViewControllers` classes for my screens, but I want to ask you how to manage a navigation with it. Let's say that I have one `ViewController` which contains a `tableView`. And i want to create a next screen. So I understand that `row` in `tableViewController` class calling

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { //... }
```

But what about next screen? I don't have it yet. Should I create a "ready" `ViewController` class? How to handle a navigation in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, when a cell is selected, you would:

- Create a new instance of your next view controller,
- Push this new instance on the UINavigationController stack.

So, first, you need to ensure that your first view controller (the one with the table view) is contained in an UINavigationController.

```
// AppDelegate, in applicationDidFinishLanching:

UIViewController *firstViewController = [[[MyCustomTableViewController alloc]
                                          initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]
                                         autorelease];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                 initWithRootViewController:firstViewController]
                                                autorelease];

[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

Then, when a cell in your table view is selected, you can write:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController *nextViewController = [[[MyNextViewController alloc]
                                             initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]
                                            autorelease];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController
                                         animated:YES]

}
```

Comment: And one question. I have to make a multiple ViewControllers or maybe "reload" one that i already have? Or maybe create a new instance of this class?

Comment: That's really a start and great explanation of what you need to start. One more thing: The Class Reference of UINavigationController contains a good introduction: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: To the question of re-using view controllers, you usually create a custom subclass of UIViewController for each of the "screens" of your app, and one instance of each custom view controller per screen.

Comment: Thanks, this responce answer my all questions!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you read the doc from Apple: [View Controllers Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html%20View%20Controllers%20Programming%20Guide)

Basically, you will have to embed your table view controller (being a **content** view controller) in a navigation controller (**container** view controller).

Then in the -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, you will instantiate a new **content** view controller, and push it on your current table view controller, via the navigation controller with this kind of message:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:<#myNextViewController#> animated:YES];
```

Be sure to read also code samples from Apple (some are pretty thin, so it's easy to understand).

Answer (score -1):

I hate IB, and have gone to some trouble to attempt to make apps without it, however it is so embedded into the workflow, that I found it easier just to grit my teeth and use it. However, there are posts that describe, to varying extent, how to develop without IB, such as:

- http://blog.shinetech.com/2009/07/15/why-would-you-use-interface-builder-for-iphone-development/
- http://www.calvinx.com/2011/02/05/iphone-app-without-interface-builder/